# Rails Mechanize datascrape query/cleaning results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm scraping a lot of data from the UCAS website (using mechanize gem) and have most of it working but when I try to pull the Entry Requirements from Scotland I run into some trouble. Below is the code I've used to find and scrape the entry requirements:

```
        entry_link = course_details.search('ul.details_tabs a').first
        if entry_link

        # If there is a link to a qualification page for the course go to that
        details_info[:entry] = process_entry(@mechanize.get(entry_link["href"]))
        end 
end


def process_entry(entry_req)
    entry_array = []
    entry_info = {}

        # Sets all data in hash
        @requirements = entry_req.search('li.qual-element.qual_range').text.strip
        entry_info[:req]          = @requirements

        #Pushes to array, and prints     
        entry_array.push(entry_info)
        print_entry_info(entry_info)
```

What this returns, however, isn't all that great. Rather than returning just one result for either Scottish highers or Advanced highers it pulls both of them and outputs them as such:

```
 BBB Typical offerAABB Typical offer
```

Is there anyway to either zone in and only pull the BBB or the AABB or a way to strip it down using gsub or something to only display the AABB or the BBB? Any help is appreciated.

Link to an example page where such data would be pulled from:
http://search.ucas.com/course/entryrequirements/448323/anthropology?Vac=2&AvailableIn=2016&IsFeatherProcessed=True&ret=providers#coursedetailsmenu

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code and the minimum data that demonstrate the problem _in the question itself_.

Comment: `course_details.search('ul.details_tabs a').first` is better written as `course_details.at('ul.details_tabs a')`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
entry_req.search('li.qual-element.qual_range').text
```

Don't use `text` with a NodeSet, which is what `search` returns. See the documentation for [NodeSet#text](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNodeSet%3Atext) and [Node#text](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode%3Atext).

You need to iterate over your found nodes and extract the text from each one. Typically we do that using `search('some selector').map(&:text)` which returns an array of text.